# Problemas com Custom Template Tags em Django 1.8.5

Tags: python-3.x, django-1.8

Boa noite!

Primeiro, gostaria que me ajudassem a melhorar este tópico, se necessário.

Bem, trabalho com Django 1.8.5, Python 3.4, virtualenv acertado e demais dependências também.

Meu problema é. Tenho duas custom template tags, uma funciona, outra não.
A que funciona é a "companies_i_recommend". Código abaixo:

```
from django import template
from portalcom.companies.models import Recommend

register = template.Library()


@register.inclusion_tag('companies/templatetags/companies_i_recommend.html')
def companies_i_recommend(user):
    recommendations = Recommend.objects.filter(user=user).count()
    context = {
        'recommendations': recommendations,    
    }    
    return context

@register.assignment_tag
def i_recommend(user, company):
    user = user
    company = company
    recommend = Recommend.objects.filter(user=user, company=company)
```

No navegador, tentando usar tag que não funciona, recebo um erro de sintaxe de template dizendo que a tag não é válida. Se uso o shell do Python, recebo este erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'i_recommend'
```

Meu objetivo é colocar a variável "recommend" no contexto de várias páginas, já que estou tentando carregá-la em um arquivo base.html.

Então, alguém pode ajudar com esse mistério? Obrigado, desde já!

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia utilizar `custom context_processor`. Assim, você irá incluir no contexto geral, em todas as páginas o que você quiser.

Cria um novo arquivo no seu app chamado por exemplo context_processors.py
Nele escreva o seguinte código:

```
def say_hello(request):
    return {
            'say_hello':"Hello",
           }
```

No seu arquivo de settings, na configuracao do template, inclua:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
      ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': ["django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                                    "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                                    "django.template.context_processors.i18n",
                                    "django.template.context_processors.media",
                                    "django.template.context_processors.static",
                                    "django.template.context_processors.tz",
                                    "suaapp.context_processors.say_hello",
                                    ...
]
```

Pronto, com isso agora em todas as páginas da aplicação haverá um novo item no contexto chamado {{say_hello}} que imprimirá no template "Hello".

Para o que você precisa, basta fazer seu método no arquivo context_processors.py e retornar o que quer mostrar no template.

Espero ter ajudado.

Se restarem dúvidas, comenta aí que tentarei explicar.